# AngularJS + webpack how to hash template htmls

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack

I have migrated our AngularJS application to use webpack - before it used gulp. in the gulp version I have used rev plugin to rev all the files (css,js and html) however in the webpack mode , I cannot find a way to add hash to the html templates - which cause issues as the browser serve old html files. How can it be fixed? below is by webpack conf file

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const OpenBrowserPlugin = require('open-browser-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

const RemoteServer = process.env.REMOTE_SERVER;
const appEnv = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const isProduction = appEnv === 'production';

const patterns = require('../server/src/main/resources/regex.json');

const appPath = path.join(__dirname, 'app');
const buildPath = path.join(__dirname, 'artifacts');

const config = {
    entry: [path.join(appPath, 'index.js')],

    output: {
        path: buildPath,
        filename: '[name].[hash].js',
        chunkFilename: '[name].[hash].js'
    },

resolve: {
    modules: ['node_modules', appPath],
    alias: {
        'ui-select-css': path.resolve('./node_modules/ui-select/dist/select.css'),
        fonts: path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets/fonts')
    }
},

module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'eslint-loader',
            options: {
                emitWarning: true,
                quiet: true
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
                MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                'css-loader',
                'resolve-url-loader'
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.less$/,
            use: [{
                loader: 'style-loader'
            }, {
                loader: 'css-loader', options: {
                    url: false,
                    sourceMap: true
                }
            }, {
                loader: 'less-loader', options: {
                    relativeUrls: false,
                    sourceMap: true
                }
            }]
        },
        {
            test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)(\?.*)?$/i,
            use: [{
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {name: '[path][name].[hash].[ext]'}
            }]
        },
        {
            test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
            use: {
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    name: '[name].[ext]',
                    outputPath: 'fonts/'
                }
            }

        },
        {
            test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'url-loader',
                    options: {limit: 10000, mimetype: 'application/octet-stream'}
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'file-loader'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.svg$/i,
            loader: 'raw-loader'
        },
        {
            test: require.resolve('angular'),
            use: [
                {loader: 'expose-loader', options: 'angular'},
            ]
        },
        {
            test: require.resolve('jquery'),
            use: [
                {loader: 'expose-loader', options: '$'},
                {loader: 'expose-loader', options: 'jQuery'},
            ]
        },
        {
            test: require.resolve('lodash'),
            use: [
                {loader: 'expose-loader', options: '_'},
            ]
        },
        {
            test: require.resolve('moment'),
            use: [
                {loader: 'expose-loader', options: 'moment'},
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.html$/,
            use: [{
                loader: 'raw-loader',
                options: {name: '[path][name].[hash].[ext]'}
            }]
        }
    ]
},

plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: path.join(appPath, 'index.html')
    }),

    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        INJECT_REGEX_HERE: JSON.stringify(patterns)
    }),

    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        {from: 'app/images', to: 'assets/images'},
        {from: 'app/fonts', to: 'assets/fonts'},
        {from: 'app/templates', to: 'assets/templates'},
        {from: 'app/silent-callback.html', to: 'silent-callback.html'},
        {from: 'node_modules/font-awesome/css', to: 'assets/font-awesome/css'},
        {from: 'node_modules/font-awesome/fonts', to: 'assets/font-awesome/fonts'},
        {from: 'node_modules/angular-ui-grid/fonts', to: 'assets/fonts'},
        {from: 'node_modules/d3/d3.min.js', to: 'assets/d3'}
    ]),

    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: '[name].[hash].css',
        chunkFilename: '[id].[hash].css'
    }),

    new OpenBrowserPlugin({url: 'http://localhost:1337'})
],

devtool: isProduction ? 'source-map' : 'inline-source-map',

devServer: {
    port: 1337
},

optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
        cacheGroups: {
            commons: {
                test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                name: 'vendors',
                chunks: 'all'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

};

```
if (RemoteServer) {
     console.log('running with remote server', RemoteServer);
     config.devServer.proxy = {
    '/occm/*': 'http://' + RemoteServer
    };
 }

if (isProduction) {
config.plugins.push(
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(buildPath)
    );
}

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? I'm looking for the same thing

Comment: As an option you can inline all html templates into js. That what we do in our app.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov how do you handle ngIncludes (if you have any)?

Comment: We have only "file-local" ng-includes, and there is no problem. (We put global templates directly to templateCache)

Answer (score 2):

One of the main benefits of using Webpack is reducing the number of requests a browser has to perform for rendering your application and making your app start faster.
To achieve this, it groups related resources together in "chunks", that get loaded together in one request. Separate loading of required single files like HTML-templates (without a specific reason) could be considered an anti-pattern here.

Best practice is grouping all related JS, HTML and CSS code together in one big bundle that gets loaded once, sometimes (for bigger apps) having a second 'vendor' bundle for the code from node_modules, speeding up development, because this chunk won't change as often.

### Alternative solution:

So in your case, if there is no specific reason for keeping things separate (which you didn't write about), I would rather recommend serving HTML together with the controlling code in one chunk instead of loading the HTML files separately.

A good and simple starting point would be to build just two chunks. Replace your whole optimization block by the following code:

```
optimization: {
  splitChunks: {
    cacheGroups: {
      commons: {
        test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
        name: 'vendor',
        chunks: 'all'
      }
    }
  }
},
```

That will build two chunks: One main chunk for all of your JS and HTML files and another one, explicitly for everything from the node_modules folder.

That way you won't have to worry about browser caches for HTML files anymore, because they are built in your main chunk, and, as a benefit, your app will start faster.

Comment: The basic point being, webpack will handle this for you automatically, you don't need to build the hashes yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I did a similar migration a couple of year and I didn't need that type of solution. My goal was encapsulate each component as a module and then lazy load as much as possible.

```
// webpack config
{
  test: /\.html$/,
  use: ['html-loader'],
},
```

Then in each component I just require styles and template like:

```
require('./_proposal-page.scss');

(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('component.myComponent', []).component('myComponent', {
    template: require('./proposal-page.html'),
    controller: MyController,
  });

  /** @ngInject */
  function MyController($log) {
    const $ctrl = this;
    $ctrl.$onInit = function() {
      $log.log('$onInit myComponent');
    }
  }
})();
if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && typeof exports !== 'undefined' && module.exports === exports) {
  module.exports = 'component.myComponent';
}
```

Webpack detect the requires and export each `.html` file as a module, it works smoothly.